# Como gerar um .jar executável usando o Maven?

Tags: java, maven

É necessário fazer alguma configuração extra para gerar um .jar executável pelo Maven? Como nunca utilizei essa tecnologia em desenvolvimento *desktop* estou um pouco perdido.

Quando construo o projeto (os logs mostram que construiu com sucesso) e tento executá-lo, nada acontece. Para ver se estava sendo lançada alguma exceção ou algo semelhante, tentei executar por linha de comando e eis a mensagem:

> Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

<kbd>[image: imagem :)]</kbd>

Meu arquivo **`pom.xml`** está assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kitty.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Kitty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>Kitty</name>
    <dependencies>
       <!-- Dependências do projeto -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Está faltando alguma configuração? Como posso corrigir isso e gerar um **`.jar`** executável como se fosse uma aplicação normal Java?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sim, está faltando especificar sua classe principal (main class). Para isso você pode usar esse plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>sua.classe.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Funcionou, mesmo reclamando da falta do `<version>`. Pode ser feita alguma configuração nesse plugin para gerar um único .jar com tudo empacotado? Pois foi gerado diversos diretórios além do "executável".

Comment: É me esqueci do <version>. Quanto aos outros arquivos diretórios criados isso é normal. Se você esta versionando seu projeto basta configurar o seu scm para ignorar a pasta target. No meu caso, como uso o Git eu crio um arquivo chamado ".gitignore" e dentro dele coloco (dentre outras coisas que eu quero que o Git ignore), o nome da pasta "target".

Answer (score 11):

A [resposta do Afonso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68817/como-gerar-um-jar-execut%C3%A1vel#answer-68821) funcionou como eu esperava e gerou um **`.jar`** que executa minha aplicação.

Até então eu não sabia que existiam *plugins* para o Maven e, pesquisando um pouco mais encontrei o [*Maven Assembly Plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) que (além de fazer a mesma coisa) ainda permite construir um único **`.jar`** com todas as dependências empacotadas.

No caso da minha aplicação, esse me pareceu mais interessante, na [página de exemplos](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/index.html) existem algumas outras situações em que o *plugin* pode ser útil. As definições que usei no meu arquivo `pom.xml` foram:

```xml
<plugins>

   <!-- ... -->

   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>
                  <mainClass>br.com.MinhaClasseMain</mainClass>
              </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
          <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>

   <!-- ... -->

</plugins>
```

> **Nota**: é possível omitir o grupo do artefato visto que o Maven possui o `org.apache.maven.plugins` como grupo padrão. E neste caso, é o mesmo grupo do *plugin*.

Comment: Nossa, obrigado, já cai exatamente no problema das dependências, voltei e vi sua resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Renan também não conheço tal tecnologia também, mas sobre o Java (e não o Maven) se eu não estiver enganado o comando `java` procura um arquivo `.class`, não é?

Para executar arquivos `jar` seria necessário o parâmetro `-jar`, como no exemplo:

```
java -jar Kitty-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Agora apareceu "nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em Kitty-1.0.jar". Deve ser algo no **`pom.xml`** mas por não conhecer a tecnologia eu não sei como corrigir.

Comment: @re22 eu acho que o problema é no manifest gerado pelo netbeans, se abrir o jar pelo winrar tem um arquivo chamado `Manifest.mf`, qual o conteúdo dele?

Comment: Tem [isso aqui](http://i.imgur.com/YATgK5v.jpg)

Comment: @re22 conforme a imagem o nome da classe era `Main` no manifest, mas no .java deveria ser outra coisa e isto ocasionou o conflito, sim parece que a solução do @Afonso parece correta, não pude testar.