# Maven: gerar JAR com Dependências / Diretório recources

Tags: java, maven, plugin, jar

Sou muito leigo com `Maven` e pelo fato de haver muito material na internet acabo ficando perdido como realizar a operação abaixo:

Preciso gerar o `JAR Runnable` do meu projeto com todas as Dependências que eu utilizei e também a pasta `java/main/resources/META-INF`.

Quem for me explicar, por favor, parta do ponto que eu tenho extremo baixo conhecimento em `Maven/Pom.xml`, pelo que andei vendo é necessário builda um pluguin com a configuração do projeto.

Segue abaixo a arvore de diretórios do meu projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para gerar um "executável", tem [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68821/4808) com a configuração de build. No meu caso resolveu.

Comment: @renan sua dica foi util, mas ainda falta intende como fazer para aplicação reconhecer as pastas 'resources' que no meu caso contem arquivos de configuração e imagens.

Comment: Qual a sua IDE ?

Comment: @DavidSchrammel desculpa não ter informado, utilizo o Eclipse mas consegui realizar o procedimento com as informações da resposta 'certa' abaixo.

Comment: Legal, no eclipse Luna você pode clicar com o botão direito e exportar, irá abrir uma tela e você pode marcar para exportar as dependências junto no jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá!!

Depois de muita busca sem sentido no Google, acabei encontrar 3 link que me ajudaram a gerar o meu JAR com as Dependências / Libraries customizada / Diretórios Resources. Segue a sequencia de link do que você vai encontrar em cada uma das fontes.

Fonte 1: Adicionar JAR próprios ou baixados da internet ao Repositório do Maven Local:
[MkYoung.com | Adicionar JAR para Repositório Maven Local](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

Fonte 2: Configurar o Maven-Shade-Plugin para encontrar a Main Class e o Boot do Spring.
[http://crunchify.com](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-only-one-executable-jar-file-with-all-required-jars-properties-and-resources/)

Fonte 3: Próprio site do `Apache Maven` com as formas de adicionar um JAR no repositório Maven local.

[https://maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Simplificando meu `Build` do `Pom.xml` ficou o seguinte abaixo:

```
<build>
    <finalName>SisAcademia</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Optional Start -->
                        <finalName>SisAcademia</finalName>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                        <!-- Optional End -->

                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>br.com.tamarozzi.app.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```