# Inserir pasta com projeto MAVEN javafX

Tags: maven, javafx

Pessoal tenho um projeto MAVEN, quando gero o projeto, ele gera o JAR principal e a pasta de LIB, que contem as biblioteca, tudo certo até ai, o que preciso é incluir uma outra pasta com outros arquivos para que meu jar possa acessar quando for necessário. Usei  comando abaixo, só que ele importa os arquivos para dentro do Jar o que não resolve meu problema, sendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem pode me dar uma luz para criar a pasta quando for da a BUILD MAVEN?

Comment: Vê se ajuda: [Como gerar um .jar executável usando o Maven?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68817/3117)

Comment: Isso eu Nao ajudou, eu consigo gerar, só que eu preciso quando gerar, gerar uma pasta com alguns arquivos, que é o que não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Para gerar com os arquivos acho que é a parte `<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>`, na [resposta do Renan](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68968/3117)